# How to make this style generic?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, styles

I have the following DataGridCell style:

```
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="DateChangeAnimation" >
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Date.ValueChanged}" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource BindProxy}, Path=Data.Columns.Date.NotifyChange}" Value="True" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" From="#1F1F1F" To="#FFFF88" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

This style has the bindings set for one column cell, as I need to apply it to 20 or more columns, is there a way to define the style once in a generic manner and to instantiate it as many times as needed specifying only the variables to bind?

Comment: I love when people downvote you but don't say why. Don't you?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but if it's what I think it is then the short answer is No (maybe Yes).

I'm saying this because I think that you're looking to be able to somehow replace the BindingExpressions you wrote without a new style being created upon each variation.

So, why maybe Yes? Well, you could use a DynamicResource and programmatically create the styles, replacing the BindingExpressions where necessary.

---

As another alternative, you could create a custom control (or UserControl) that exposes dependency properties and then bind your variation of values to those properties, but that might not be worth the trouble.

---

Here's what I'm guessing you're trying to accomplish by using a simpler example.

```
<Style x:Key="MyDesiredGenericStyle" x:TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <Border ...>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeGenericWay}" />
            <ContentPresenter />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
  </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

vs.

<Style x:Key="MyDesiredStyleA" x:TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <Border ...>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropA}" />
            <ContentPresenter />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
  </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyDesiredStyleB" x:TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <Border ...>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropB}" />
            <ContentPresenter />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
  </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You got what I'm talking about, as a programmer I hate to have repeated code. I'm relatively new to WPF and I've never used the DynamicResource. I will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend going against DRY in this case, or looking into a UserControl/Custom Control with exposed Dependency Properties. Trust me, both of those would be easier than programmatically creating Styles. UserControl/Custom Control might not be worth the trouble, but it's much better than programmatically creating the styles. Seriously consider copy/pasting this unless it is that bad.

Comment: Yeah, I hate copy paste but probably it would be the only way.

Comment: Not to complicate things, but *some* things you can inherit by using the `BasedOn` property in your style... won't help you in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give it key so it will be set to all DataGridCell in the application by default.

Comment: What I need is to replace the Bindings. Each cell has different bindings, of course.

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood your post.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, remove the key:

```
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Date.ValueChanged}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource BindProxy}, Path=Data.Columns.Date.NotifyChange}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" From="#1F1F1F" To="#FFFF88" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: -1 for not reading other answers on a 2 answer question and repeating one.